# Create an horizontal menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development and I have to build an Android version of a iOs app. I have to build an horizontal menu in the bottom of the screen. Something like MOVIES|TV SHOWS|PERSONAL VIDEOS in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXe6y.png)

How do you suggest me to proceed? If I did an activity layout with a tabbed o linear layout at the bottom and fragments for the above contents?

Comment: Check this out http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: Thank you but I would follow the iOs app and don't use an action bar.

Comment: Thea add linear layout put the menus inside that.

Comment: i think u can find ur answer in this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837860/horizontal-menus

Answer (score 2):

**@Ivan Lasorsa :**

You can use  [ViewPager Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)  as main layout and for individual pager views we use *Fragments*. The tabs are part of **[Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)**.

**Swipe-view** should consume the entire layout, then your layout looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So please take a look [Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) Here . I hope it will helps you .

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend bottom tab bar

because it causes the wrong touch

Pure-Android : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

but if you have to implement, you can read to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431480/2530660

Comment: You can use tabs layout from design support library

Answer (score 1):

It's the tabbed activity, here is the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) ;)